# Determining whether a Time series is white noise

Tags: time-series, white-noise

I have a time series of log-returns of a stock. I want to determine whether the time series is just white noise or if there are some other pattern. How to I use the definition of white noise to make a conclusion?

Comment: Can you add a graph of what your time series currently looks like, and its ACF?

Comment: anyway, financial time series implies "some other pattern" ,all the time.

Answer (score 7):

You want to look at an [autocorrelation function](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/60) (ACF) plot. If no lags are significantly correlated, then you basically have white noise or a MA(q) process aka moving average.

You can use this guide here to compare what your ACF plot looks like to determine if your time-series is "white noise" or not. [Guide to ACF/PACF Plots](ftp://ftp.boulder.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/support/Stats/Docs/Statistics/Miscellaneous/Guide_to_ACF_PACF_plots.pdf)

Also, feel free to browse through previous time-series related posts like:

1. [How to interpret ACF and PACF plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117337/how-to-interpret-acf-and-pacf-plots)
2. [Help interpreting ACF- and PACF-plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/help-interpreting-acf-and-pacf-plots)
3. [Interpreting ACF and PACF Plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140673/interpreting-acf-and-pacf-plot)